# Filtering local storage data by field and output it to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to work out how to achieve something.  I have a type of map where you can click on a country and enter some data.  When the data is submitted, I store it in local storage

```
$('#question-form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let country = $('#hidden-input').val();
    let questionOne = $('#questionOne').val();
    let questionTwo = $('#questionTwo').val();
    
    let clientObj = {
        country : country,
        questionOne : questionOne,
        questionTwo: questionTwo
    };
    
    let clientsArr = [];

    if(!localStorage.getItem('Countries')) {
        clientsArr.push(clientObj);
        localStorage.setItem('Countries', JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
    } else {
        clientsArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Countries'));
        clientsArr.push(clientObj);
        localStorage.setItem('Countries', JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
    }

    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

After a while my local storage becomes full of data that takes the following form

```
[{country: "United Kingdom", questionOne: "test", questionTwo: "test"},…]
    0: {country: "United Kingdom", questionOne: "test", questionTwo: "test"}
    1: {country: "Ireland", questionOne: "test 2", questionTwo: "test 2"}
    2: {country: "Iran", questionOne: "Test 3", questionTwo: "Test 3"}
    3: {country: "United Kingdom", questionOne: "Test 4", questionTwo: "Test 4"}
```

What I am trying to do is display these results. So on my page I have some placeholders

```
<div id="display">
    <div id="country-name"></div>
    <div class="question-one-data"></div>
    <div class="question-two-data"></div>
</div>
```

I have then got to this point

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('Countries')) {
    $('#display').html('<p>No results to display</p>');
} else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('Countries')))
}
```

So if there is no data it will let the user know.  It is in the else I am a bit stuck.  Now displaying the data is not a problem.  What I am struggling with is filtering.  So I want the country to be set to the country-name placeholder,
however, it should only display a country once.  So I essentially need to filter my results by countries.  In my example, you can see that there were two entries for United Kingdom, so the output I am after is

```
<div id="display">
    <div id="country-name">United Kingdom</div>
    <div class="question-one-data">test</div>
    <div class="question-two-data">test</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="question-one-data">Test 4</div>
    <div class="question-two-data">Test 4</div>
    <hr>
    <div id="country-name">Ireland</div>
    <div class="question-one-data">test 2</div>
    <div class="question-two-data">test 2</div>
    ...
</div>
```

How would I go about filtering my data by country name and then achieve the structure as shown above?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want to correct your data to have each object `countryName` with a certain value to occur only once in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have your data in a variable called `answers`. You can create a list of all unique country names with:

```
const countries = Array.from(new Set(answers.map(a => a.country)))
```

Then, you may reshape your data and store all answers for a given country in a new array:

```
const countriesWithAnswers = countries.map(countryName => ({
  name: countryName,
  answers: answers
    .filter(answer => answer.country === countryName)
    .map(({ questionOne, questionTwo }) => ({ questionOne, questionTwo }))
}))
```

To display the data, you can then iterate over the `answers` array for every element of `countriesWithAnswers`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your task correctly, here is my intended solution

First you need to sort your array by the country name:

```
countriesArray = [
  {country: "United Kingdom", questionOne: "test", questionTwo: "test"}, 
  {country: "Ireland", questionOne: "test 2", questionTwo: "test 2"}, 
  {country: "Iran", questionOne: "Test 3", questionTwo: "Test 3"}, 
  {country: "United Kingdom", questionOne: "Test 4", questionTwo: "Test 4"}
  ...
]

countriesArray.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.country < b.country) return -1
    if (a.country > b.country) return 1
    return 0
})
```

Then you can iterate over it, to collect all the data defined for particular country name:

```
let currentCountry
const results = {}

for (const item of countriesArray) {
    const { country, questionOne, questionTwo } = item;

    if (currentCountry === undefined || currentCountry !== country) {
        currentCountry = country
    }

    if (!results[currentCountry]) {
        results[currentCountry] = []
    }

    results[currentCountry].push({
        questionOne,
        questionTwo,
    })
}
```

After that you can again iterate over it and render some HTML.
Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

your original array of countries

```
let countries =[
  {country: "United Kingdom", questionOne: "test", questionTwo: "test"},
  {country: "Ireland", questionOne: "test 2", questionTwo: "test 2"},
  {country: "Iran", questionOne: "Test 3", questionTwo: "Test 3"},
  {country: "United Kingdom", questionOne: "Test 4", questionTwo: "Test 4"}
];
```

declare a variable named sortedCountries. iterate over the countries array, and for each country check if the country's name do not exist is the sorted array. then push it into the sorted array.

```
let sortedCountries = [];

countries.forEach(country => {
  if (!sortedCountries.some(el => el.country === country.country)) {
    sorted.push(country)
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of unique countries by using the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object. This object can hold a collection of values with the condition that each value is unique, which makes filtering for duplicates an easy task. Turning the set back into an array makes it possible to use it for further looping and manipulation.

Then loop over each country name with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to locate the first occurrence of the country name in the array that you're working with. This will create a new array with objects that haven't occurred before.

```js
const questions = [
  {
    country: "United Kingdom",
    questionOne: "test",
    questionTwo: "test"
  },
  {
    country: "Ireland",
    questionOne: "test 2",
    questionTwo: "test 2"
  },
  {
    country: "Iran",
    questionOne: "Test 3",
    questionTwo: "Test 3"
  },
  {
    country: "United Kingdom",
    questionOne: "Test 4",
    questionTwo: "Test 4"
  }
];

const filterQuestions = questions => {
  const uniqueCountries = Array.from(new Set(
    questions.map(({ country }) => country))
  );
  return uniqueCountries.map(country =>
    questions.find(question => question.country === country)
  );
}

const uniqueQuestions = filterQuestions(questions);

console.log(uniqueQuestions);
```